# C open socket on a specific IP

Tags: c, linux, sockets, posix

My website can be accessed using any of 2 different static IPs (IPv4).

Is it possible to open a TCP connection to another server, specifying which of the 2 IPs to use as a return address ?

x.x.x.x (my server) => z.z.z.z (destination server)
y.y.y.y (my server) => z.z.z.z (destination server)

Error-checking, etc. in this example has been omitted for simplicity sakes :

```c
struct addrinfo hints, *result;
hints.ai_flags = 0;
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
hints.ai_addrlen = 0;
hints.ai_canonname = NULL;
hints.ai_addr = NULL;
hints.ai_next = NULL;

getaddrinfo(domain, "80", &hints, &result);

socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like @hochl says, you use the `bind` system call:

```
struct sockaddr_in sin = { 0 };
int sock;

/* Create a socket address, with a specific port and (local) ipnumber */
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_port = htons(80);
inet_aton("1.2.3.4", &sin.sin_addr);

/* Create socket */
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

/* Bind socket to the local address */
bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, sizeof(sin));

/* Now connect to remote server... */
/* connect(...) */
```

It should be noted that use of `inet_aton` is normally discouraged, in favor of `inet_pton`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but can't you `bind` your socket to one of your local addresses before you connect? In this case you may choose which of your IPs is used for the connection.